# Why my `set_terminate` is not being called and how to make it to be called?

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin

I am on Windows 10 using `Cygwin` with `Mintty Terminal` and `g++ 5.4.0` following this example on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/set_terminate/.

```
// set_terminate example
#include <iostream>       // std::cerr
#include <exception>      // std::set_terminate
#include <cstdlib>        // std::abort

void myterminate () {
  std::cerr << "terminate handler called\n";
  abort();  // forces abnormal termination
}

int main (void) {
  std::set_terminate (myterminate);
  throw 0;  // unhandled exception: calls terminate handler
  return 0;
}
```

And compiling it with `g++ -o main main.cpp && ./main`, however nothing is being printed. So I am assuming my handler is not being called. What is missing to it works?

---

If I compile it with the Visual Studio compiler it does work fine running `cl.bat /EHsc /Femain.exe main.cpp && ./main`:

```
$ cl.bat /EHsc /Femain.exe main.cpp && ./main
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj
terminate handler called
```

Here `cl.bat` is:

```
@echo off

:: Path to your Visual Studio folder.
::
:: Examples:
::     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0
::     F:\VisualStudio2015
set VISUAL_STUDIO_FOLDER=F:\VisualStudio2015

:: Load compilation environment
call "%VISUAL_STUDIO_FOLDER%\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

:: Invoke compiler with any options passed to this batch file
"%VISUAL_STUDIO_FOLDER%\VC\bin\cl.exe" %*
```

I put it on my PATH variable to be able to call the Visual Studio compiler and tools from the Cygwin environment & `Mintty Terminal`.